# Building Share extension in android

Tags: android, share

I have created an app for sharing the web page contents (Title, Image, and article texts) . I want to implement a share extension in web browser page to share the content of the page with my App. How can i build that share option and get data to share?

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the webpage content and then share it in the same way you share content from your app.
I hope the below parser will help you, or you can find something better for your use-case.
http://jsoup.org
**Further reference:**
For Example and Tutorial,
 
https://github.com/AndyYiu/JSoup-Android-App
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Comment: This is not the solution I am looking for. Please be clear that I need a share extension of my application  in web browser for sharing the page content when I click on the share extension of my App.

Comment: From the above parser you will get the content of the webpage. You can put the content as extra for intent and start the intent using startActivity(). If you are expecting something else please describe it more clearly.

Comment: Please refer the the android docs: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html.